# Group Push Notifications in ParsePushBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm trying to put together several notifications in one as does Whatsapp, using a custom ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.

```
public class ParseAppReceiver  extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

private String mStringMessage;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@Override
protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPushReceive(context, intent);

    JSONObject data = getDataFromIntent(intent);

    try {
        mStringMessage = data.getString("alert");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("Example")
            .setContentText(mStringMessage)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setGroup(GROUP_PUSH_KEY)
            .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notif);

}

private JSONObject getDataFromIntent(Intent intent) {
  ...
}
```

I assign a group to the notice but are not grouped if not that the second push notification **overwrite** the first.

If any have idea please help me, Thanks in advance.